# how to make sure that subsequent dataflow jobs will be executed on the same machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am able to load multiple CSV files to bigquery by dataflow using a for loop.
But in this case, a new dataflow is getting triggered each time resulting with additional overhead.

DataFlow part of my code:

```
def run(abs_csv_file_name="", table_name="", argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input_csv_file',
                        dest='input_csv_file',
               default='gs://{0}/{1}'.format(bucket_name,abs_csv_file_name),
                        help='Input file to process.')
    parser.add_argument('--output_stage_bq',
                        dest='output_stage_bq',
                        default='{0}:{1}.{2}'.format(project_id,stage_dataset_name,table_name),
                        help='Output file to write results to.')

    parser.add_argument('--output_target_bq',
                        dest='output_target_bq',
                        default='{0}:{1}.{2}'.format(project_id,dataset_name,table_name),
                        help='Output file to write results to.')

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    # delete_a_bq_table(table_name)
    table_spec = "{0}:{1}.{2}".format(project_id, stage_dataset_name, table_name)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p1:
        data_csv = p1 | 'Read CSV file' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input_csv_file)
        dict1 = (data_csv | 'Format to json' >> (beam.ParDo(Split())))
        (dict1 | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                            known_args.output_stage_bq,
                                            schema=product_revenue_schema
                                            ))
        fullTable = (p1 | 'ReadFromBQ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(table_spec)))
        (fullTable | 'writeToBQ another dataset' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(known_args.output_target_bq,
                                schema = product_revenue_schema))
```

I am sure there should be a better way, than calling run function each time.

```
for i in range(len(table_names)):
    find_product_revenue_schema_and_column_name(table_name=table_names[i])

    run(abs_csv_file_name=abs_file_names[i], table_name=table_names[i])
```

I need to write a code which can assure that subsequent dataflow jobs will be executed on the same machine, so that machine setup time can be saved.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding on the architecture of Dataflow.  There should never be an occurrence where you concern yourself where Dataflow parts run.  Dataflow is by definition a distributed environment.  In your code fragments, there is no sign of Dataflow.  I'd like to suggest that you rework your question and add a lot more detail ... at a minimum, describe how you are interacting with dataflow.

Comment: 1. I have multiple tables to do ETL for.                                                 2. There are few additional packages I need to pass through --requirements. I want to execute this run() for all these tables. So what will be the better approach to save time of setting up dataflow machine each time by using the same configured machine each time.